# Curinga or coringa?

Tags: ortografia

Sometimes when we translate the word he wildcard appears as *Coringa*, other times it is shown as *Curinga*.

After all which one is correct, *Coringa* or *Curinga*?

---

Notei que alguns textos usam a palavra *Coringa* e outros usam a palavra *Curinga*.

Afinal de contas, qual é o correto, *Coringa* ou *Curinga*?

Comment: Só não entendi porque você postou isso em inglês e não em português.

Comment: @VictorStafusa algumas perguntas minhas eu sei a resposta eu talvez possa adicionar em Portugues, mas a intenção foi colocar para os que não falam Portugues nativamente, no entanto irei editar. Grato!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The correct translation of "Wildcard" is Portuguese for "Joker", as said by [@Earthliŋ](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/a/428/8).

- Curinga: playing card
- Coringa: sail used in small boats

However the reason for the incorrect use of the word Joker in Brazil was caused due to the character of the batman comic book, because in 1953, [Editora Brasil-América Ltda. (EBAL)](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBAL), of Rio de Janeiro (which published stories in Batman comics in Brazil), decided that the word *Curinga* (the correct synonym for the Joker) was very ugly and replaced by *Coringa* and this was the reason for the "confusion" with words.

---

A tradução correta de *Wildcard* para o Português é *Curinga*, como já dito pelo [@Earthliŋ](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/a/428/8)

- Curinga: carta de baralho
- Coringa: vela usada em pequenas embarcações

No entanto o motivo do uso incorreto da palavra Coringa no Brasil foi ocasionada devido ao personagem do gibi/hq *batman*, pois em 1953, a [Editora Brasil-América Ltda. (EBAL)](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBAL), do Rio de Janeiro, que publicou as histórias em quadrinhos do Batman no Brasil decidiu que a palavra *Curinga*, o sinônimo correto para o *Joker* (em inglês), era muito feia e trocou-a por *Coringa* e este foi o motivo da "confusão" com as palavras.

<sub>Source (fonte): https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coringa_(DC_Comics)#Coringa_pr.C3.A9-Crise_nas_Infinitas_Terras</sub>

Comment: HAHA, não sabia dessa diferença @GuilhermeNascimento

Comment: Gostei do HAHA, foi praticamente uma homenagem pro personagem -- HAHA! http://i.stack.imgur.com/ndMd8.jpg

Comment: Devia ter pensado dessa forma :P

Answer (score 5):

From Aurélio (português brasileiro)

> **curinga**
>
> 1. Carta de baralho, que, em certos jogos, muda de valor segundo a combinação que o parceiro tem em mão. [Sin.: *dunga* (N.E.) e *melé* (MA e AL). Cf. *curingão*.]
> 2. [...]
>
>    [...]
>
> ---
>
> **coringa**
>
> *sustantivo feminino*
>
> 1. Pequena vela triangular, us. à proa das canoas de embono.
> 2. Vela quadrangular pequena, que se usa à proa das barcaças.
>
> *substantivo masculino*
>
> 3. Moço de barcaça.
> 4. Pessoa feia e raquítica. [Cf. *curinga*]

So, *curinga* means "wildcard" and *coringa* doesn't.

Comment: Só para referência não se usa curinga em Portugal e sim *joker*.